# Email sending error in elastalert. SMTPSenderRefused: (530, '5.5.1 Authentication Required)

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

*i got gmail authentication error. my config and error message as below
    I already allowed less secure apps in gmail.*

#### **Config.yaml file email section as below**

```
 name: frequency_rule
 type: frequency
 index: security
 num_events: 50

 timeframe:
   days: 1

 filter:
   - term:
       host.keyword : "azure-2"
 alert:
   - email
 email:
   "to_address@gmail.com"

 smtp_host: "smtp.gmail.com"
 smtp_port: "465"
 smtp_ssl: true
 from_addr: "from_address@gmail.com"
 user: "from_address@gmail.com"
 password: "password"
```

#### **Error message as below**

```
PS C:\Users\smiforce-2ndPC\Downloads\Compressed\elastalert-master\elastalert-master> python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --config ./config.yaml --rule ./alert_rules/frequency4.yaml
INFO:elastalert:Starting up
INFO:elastalert:Queried rule frequency_rule4 from 2017-11-20 09:48 Central Standard Time to 2017-11-21 09:48 Central Standard Time: 24 / 24 hits
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\smiforce-2ndPC\Downloads\Compressed\elastalert-master\elastalert-master\elastalert\elastalert.py", line 1246, in alert
return self.send_alert(matches, rule, alert_time=alert_time, retried=retried)
File "C:\Users\smiforce-2ndPC\Downloads\Compressed\elastalert-master\elastalert-master\elastalert\elastalert.py", line 1326, in send_alert
alert.alert(matches)
File "elastalert\alerts.py", line 451, in alert
self.smtp.sendmail(self.from_addr, to_addr, email_msg.as_string())
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 737, in sendmail
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
SMTPSenderRefused: (530, '5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError l4sm636961ioc.69 - gsmtp', 'from_address@gmail.com')

ERROR:root:Uncaught exception running rule frequency_rule4: (530, '5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError l4sm636961ioc.69 - gsmt
```

Comment: Are you using two-step verification on this gmail account?

Answer (score 2):

The `user` and `password` fields should not be stored in the same config.yaml file but in [another file](http://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#email) which is referenced in config.yaml.

For instance, create another file named `auth.yaml` and add the `user` and `password` configuration into it:

```
user: "from_address@gmail.com"
password: "password"
```

Then in config.yaml you can reference that file using this setting:

```
smtp_auth_file: "/path/to/auth.yaml"
```

Comment: i tried both ways and finally realiced that i had 1 wrong letter in my password... -.-, but your way runs correctly

Comment: Anything more needed to close this answer?